# When to start worrying about netcode?

Tags: c++, sockets, game-engine, multiplayer

I'm currently working on a C++/SDL/OpenGL game. I've already made a few small games, but only local ones (no netcode). So I know how to make the engine, but I'm unsure about the netcode.
Can I firstly create the full engine for split-screen play and later on add the netcode or will this make everything complicated? Do I already have to take netcode into consideration while programming the basic game engine or is it also okay to just put it on top of the game after it runs fine on one machine?

It's a 2D shooter type game, if that matters. And no, I don't like to change my choice of programming language/window manager/api because I already implemented the bare bones of the game. I'm just curous how this issue is approached best.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the "netcode" as well. Could you restate more clearly what the problem you're trying to solve is?

Comment: AFAIK, if you're just sending player coordinates over the network then you can probably tack it on later. If you need synchronization then you should plan it out now.

Comment: Ideally, split screens should be entirely independent of networking. You should be able to have some way of saying "I want a Camera A shown in this region of the screen and Camera B shown in this region of the screen." and of course have support for multiple cameras in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for a network oriented game there are five concepts too keep in mind:

- events
- dispatcher
- synchronization
- rendering
- simulation

**Events**. A game engine is a event software, that means over a state of each generic object in the game (can be a unit, GUI, etc), you do an action, that means, you call a function or do nothing.

**Dispatcher** take each event change and dispatch that change to another subsystem.

**Synchronization** means that over a change of event, all clients in network must be advised throw his dispatcher over that change, in this way all players can see the changes of other players, render and simulate same things at same time.

**Rendering** The render read parameters and relevant states for each object and draw in screen. For example, is you have a property for each unit named **life_points**, you can draw a normal unit if *life_points>50* and a damage unit if *life_point>0* and *life_point<50* and a destroyed unit if *life_point=0*. Render dont make changes in objects, just draw what read from them.

**Simulation** read every object and perform some task taking on count states and properties, for example, if you have cero point of life, you mark the state of a unit as DEAD (for example) or change de GUI, or if a unit get close to another of a enemy team, you change the state from static to move moving close to that another unit. Plus this, here you make the physics of units, changing positions, rotations, etc etc... as you have all objects synchronized over network, everybody will be watching the same thing.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question: What happens when life_point is equal to 50? Hahaha, just kidding, nice answer ^.^

Answer (score 2):

*In theory*, all you need is a good enough design.  Write enough abstract classes and BAM! you can pop out one user interface (i.e. local-only) for another one (networked).  I wouldn't believe the theory, though.

It's possible to do what you want, but it involves taking into consideration all of the new issues you address when dealing with networked gameplay - syncing views for multiple users, what to do when one user drops their network link (how to detect when one user drops their network link, of course), network latency in receiving user input, handling lag on one side and not the other.  Networked programming is completely different, and some of the aspects (largely ones dealing with synchronization) may impact your core engine itself.  Even "just showing two views" gets a lot tougher, because you now have data on two completely different machines, and the data isn't necessarily the same.

My suggestion would be to do the opposite of what you're hoping for.  Get the networking code working first with minimal graphics.  In fact, console messages will be far more important than pretty graphics.  You already have experience with making the graphics of other games - work the most questionable technology first.  Get a good feel of all the things the networked code will ask of you, then focus on the graphics afterwards.

Comment: I can't upvote it, but that's a pretty good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add in netcode as soon as you can. If you don't do this you may have to overhaul a lot of the engine later in the dev cycle, so better to do it early.

It also depends on how complex the game is, but the same principles still stand. Best not to tack it on at the last second

Hope this helps!